# JSP parsing issue with tomcat 7

Tags: jsp, tomcat, web-applications

I have created one project. This project is running well with tomcat 6.
But when i run my project with tomcat 7, i got the problem:
When i start tomcat server,it starts without any error or exception.
but when i am trying to run my project in web-browser, it displays whole jsp page as it is, means whole jsp code in browser, but still cant get any error or exception through that i can figure out the issue.

I am using `apache-tomcat-7.0.29` and `jstl.jar` library.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's minetype problem, check your web.xml in tomcat/conf, if contains this cdoe :

```
<!-- The mapping for the JSP servlet -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jspx</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```